# Aggregated results from subquery in MySQL don't preserve one of my fields

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In order to pluck out a few key rows of data from a user session, I'm attempting to process the results of a subquery via a subsequent `group by` aggregation, but I'm finding that one of my columns from the subquery isn't carrying over.

I have three tables: one a set of `user_actions` that can be tracked in a web app, another contains `user_events` instances of said action and a third, `player_keys`, contains the session IDs that are used to bind multiple user_events into a single session.

Due to a quirk in the way the `user_actions` were defined, a particular `user_action` instance is sometimes identified by a `quantity` value that is passed along with it and sometimes each possible outcome has its own `user_action`.

So given a series of `user_actions`...

```
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id |       NAME        | campaign_id |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| 15 | Theme Vote Age    |         301 |
| 18 | Theme Vote Gender |         301 |
| 20 | Theme 5 Selected  |         301 |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
```

...I have `user_events` like this

```
+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| player_key_id | user_action_id | quantity |      created_at     |
+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
|           123 |             15 |       50 | 2019-10-11 12:34:56 |
|           123 |             18 |        2 | 2019-10-11 12:34:57 |
|           123 |             20 |        1 | 2019-10-11 12:34:58 |
+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
```

My query is a two step process via a subquery: First I query the player keys IDs and theme vote number in a subquery and then I join that up with another query that looks up other rows from those player key IDs (i.e. user sessions)  to add in the other two fields I want (rewritten to use `INNER JOIN` syntax as I think Gordon suggested in [his comment], ([Aggregated results from subquery in MySQL don't preserve one of my fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331953/aggregated-subquery-in-mysql-doesnt-preserve-one-of-my-fields?noredirect=1#comment103021655_58331953)) use a `CASE` statement as per [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332674/122864) and removed a superflous join in the `player_keys` table, per [tcadidot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331953/aggregated-results-from-subquery-in-mysql-dont-preserve-one-of-my-fields?noredirect=1#comment103023292_58331953)):

```
SELECT ue.player_key_id, vd.theme_vote,
    max(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age', quantity, 0)) as theme_age,
    max(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender', quantity, 0)) as theme_gender
FROM user_events AS ue
INNER JOIN user_actions ua
    ON ua.id = ue.user_action_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ue.player_key_id AS player_key_id, 
        max(CASE ua.name
            WHEN 'Theme 1 Selected' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Theme 2 Selected' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Theme 3 Selected' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Theme 4 Selected' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Theme 5 Selected' THEN 5
            ELSE 6
        END) as theme_vote
    FROM user_events ue
    INNER JOIN user_actions ua
        ON ue.user_action_id = ua.id
    WHERE ua.campaign_id = 301
        AND ua.name LIKE 'Theme % Selected'
        AND date(ue.created_at) = current_date
    GROUP BY ue.player_key_id
    ) vd
    ON ue.player_key_id = vd.player_key_id
WHERE (ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age' OR ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender')
GROUP BY ue.player_key_id
HAVING theme_age > 1 AND theme_age < 100 AND theme_gender != 3;
```

My thinking here is that the inner query's `GROUP BY` is needed because each session, grouped by the `player_key_id` contains one set of theme vote data (including one that matches 'Theme % Selected'. The outer query groups by the `player_key_id` again because each session contains one 'Theme Vote Age' and 'Theme Vote Gender' `user_action` that I've looked up and gotten two rows back for per session.

What I'm expecting to get back is something like this

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| player_key_id | theme_vote | theme_age | theme_gender |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           123 |          5 |        50 |            2 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           163 |          1 |        37 |            1 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           748 |          2 |        28 |            1 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

But what I'm getting back is

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| player_key_id | theme_vote | theme_age | theme_gender |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           123 |          6 |        50 |            2 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           163 |          6 |        37 |            1 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|           748 |          6 |        28 |            1 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

So basically, something is turning `theme_vote` to 6 across all groupings. My subquery by itself works fine. It returns rows like this as expected, where `theme_vote` spans 1-6:

```
+---------------+------------+
| player_key_id | theme_vote |
+---------------+------------+
|           123 |          5 |
+---------------+------------+
|           724 |          2 |
+---------------+------------+
|           833 |          3 |
+---------------+------------+
|           298 |          2 |
+---------------+------------+
|           529 |          6 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Running this on different days returns different amounts of data, suggesting that the date filter works, and the `campaign_id` filter is successful too.

The number of rows returned by the subquery is also significantly lower than the whole query.

Refer fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8U2WoHG7tzimFbEZP956kq/0

For further clarification, I'm using the `GROUP BY` in the outer query to turn this:

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| player_key_id | theme_vote | theme_age | theme_gender |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|      12160443 |          1 |        33 |            0 |
|      12160443 |          1 |         0 |            2 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

...into this:

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| player_key_id | theme_vote | theme_age | theme_gender |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|      12160443 |          1 |        33 |            2 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hint:  Use modern, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: abd you are missing player_keys table where you get your player_key_id

Comment: Your subquery does not aggregate anything.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this the `INNER JOIN ... ON` syntax? I'll give that a shot.

@nbk I didn't think my outer query needs that again, since the data returned links up with the player key field of user_events and I don't need any further data from the player keys table.

@Uueerdo That is correct, but the outer query does.

Comment: I don't think my `INNER JOIN` rewrite solved my problem. Still seeing the same output.

Comment: @Eric I've used `GROUP BY` successfully lots of times, but I'm relatively new to subqueries and complex queries like this one. Any particular pointers on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: @JoostSchuur Your inner query is pointless to use `GROUP BY` since you don't have any aggregation.

Comment: @JoostSchuur Your query won't run in any other dbms other than MySQL.

Comment: @Eric I tried tossing in a `max()` statement, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I'm pretty much stumped here.

Comment: Remove the subquery's `GROUP BY` and report back.

Comment: Please include `player_keys` table and data sample and also the column `campaign_id ` from table `user_actions` and column `created_at` from table `user_events`. If these are not required, you may omit them from your query. P/S: without the `player_keys` table and column `campaign_id, created_at` and changing to `SELECT ue.player_key_id AS player_key_id ... GROUP BY ue.player_key_id ` in the sub-query, you'll get the expected result.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clauses are needed to group events by the player session. 
@Parfait Otherwise the results are even more unexpected. I have added a `MAX` to aggregate just in case that makes a difference (it didn't). The subquery executes fine (see sample output)

Comment: @tcadidot0 I've filled in some more details in the original post. You were right, the `player_keys` table is not actually needed. I took it out (but the problem still persists).

Comment: @JoostSchuur , I've created a fiddle for your situation and added into your question. The current example and query you given actually return the expected value. You can edit the fiddle to insert any missing data if required and don't forget to save. Then you can paste the new saved link in your question

Comment: Thanks @tcadidot0. I've played around with the fiddle and can see that it works with the sample data. I modified it a little to add even comment out a row to see if the problem is triggered by some sessions not containing all the events for the actions in question. Clearly there is some other complexity in the full dataset or table definition that differs from this stripped down example.

Comment: You are still running an incorrect aggregate query as `vd.theme_vote` needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause of outer query. If you turn on the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_ON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode in MySQL, then restart server, this query should correctly error out like any compliant SQL database. Otherwise you may receive unexpected results. Sadly this mode turned off is a disservice to newcomers of SQL.

Comment: @JoostSchuur your subquery having GROUP BY basically makes it "give me random values associated with each player_key_id". If there are multiple events/actions for a particular player_key_id value (for campaign 301), it is just going to give you (effectively) a random one found for each player_key_id. There is almost never a time when GROUP BY without aggregation actually makes sense; adding aggregation you don't want or need does not "fix" unnecessary GROUPing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's too long to put in comment.  What happen if you change your inner query to this?

```
SELECT ue.player_key_id
    , (
        CASE ua.name
            WHEN 'Theme 1 Selected' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Theme 2 Selected' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Theme 3 Selected' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Theme 4 Selected' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Theme 5 Selected' THEN 5
            ELSE 6
        END
) AS theme_vote
FROM user_events ue
INNER JOIN user_actions ua ON ue.user_action_id = ua.id
```

Comment: More elegant (learned something, thanks!), but the problem still persists (updated query and more details in my original post)

Comment: @JoostSchuur Is the inner query working as expected?  If the inner query is correct, then we go to the outer query.  What is wrong with the outer query?  Actually describe what is the inner query, and what you want to achieve in the outer query?

Comment: I've copied some of the results of both the inner query as stated above and the modified complete query that has `GROUP BY` and `MAX` statements stripped, so I can see the data that I'm trying to group better here: https://gist.github.com/jschuur/0e3a4e4c3a1ca7f998fcda368d20723c

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL's [own documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) regarding `GROUP BY` clause in SQL-1992 and SQL-1999 standards:

> SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the `SELECT` list,
>   `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to nonaggregated columns
>   that are not named in the `GROUP BY` clause.
>
> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature
>   T301 if they are functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns:

Therefore, your outer query does not adhere to both SQL standards for two reasons: (1) the non-aggregated column, `vd.theme_vote`, is not listed in `GROUP BY` clause and (2) this same column does not appear to be functionally dependent of the included column, `ue.player_key_id`, basing off table source and name.

```
SELECT ue.player_key_id, vd.theme_vote,
...
GROUP BY ue.player_key_id                                          -- MISSING COLUMN
HAVING theme_age > 1 AND theme_age < 100 AND theme_gender != 3;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL's [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_ON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode disabled allows the above query to run without error and even admits it does not adhere to functional dependence as documented below (emphasis added) which is why you receive strange, unexpected results.

> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the `SELECT` list, `HAVING` condition, or
>   `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns **even if the columns
>   are NOT functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns**. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. In this case, *the server is free to
>   choose ANY value from each group*, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
>   want.

---

Therefore, consider conforming to the SQL standard and properly run an aggregate query. If you intend for one *theme_vote* value per `ue.player_key_id`, run the `MAX` aggregation in outer level.

```
-- CONVERT SELECT COLUMN TO AGGREGATE CALCULATION
SELECT ue.player_key_id, 
       MAX(vd.theme_vote) as theme_vote,
       MAX(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age', quantity, 0)) as theme_age,
       MAX(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender', quantity, 0)) as theme_gender
FROM user_events AS ue
INNER JOIN user_actions ua
    ON ua.id = ue.user_action_id
INNER JOIN (
    -- NO AGGREGATION IN SUBQUERY
    SELECT ue.player_key_id AS player_key_id, 
           CASE ua.name
               WHEN 'Theme 1 Selected' THEN 1
               WHEN 'Theme 2 Selected' THEN 2
               WHEN 'Theme 3 Selected' THEN 3
               WHEN 'Theme 4 Selected' THEN 4
               WHEN 'Theme 5 Selected' THEN 5
               ELSE 6
           END) as theme_vote
    FROM user_events ue
    INNER JOIN user_actions ua
        ON ue.user_action_id = ua.id
    WHERE ua.campaign_id = 301
        AND ua.name LIKE 'Theme % Selected'
        AND date(ue.created_at) = current_date
    ) vd
    ON ue.player_key_id = vd.player_key_id
WHERE (ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age' OR ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender')
GROUP BY ue.player_key_id
HAVING theme_age > 1 
   AND theme_age < 100 
   AND theme_gender != 3;
```

Alternatively using CTE with the [`WITH` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), a new addition to MySQL 8:

```
WITH vd AS (
  -- NO AGGREGATION IN SUBQUERY
  ...same subquery...
)

-- CONVERT SELECT COLUMN TO AGGREGATE CALCULATION
SELECT ue.player_key_id, 
       MAX(vd.theme_vote) as theme_vote,
       MAX(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age', quantity, 0)) as theme_age,
       MAX(if(ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender', quantity, 0)) as theme_gender
FROM user_events AS ue
INNER JOIN user_actions ua
    ON ua.id = ue.user_action_id
INNER JOIN vd
    ON ue.player_key_id = vd.player_key_id
WHERE (ua.name = 'Theme Vote Age' OR ua.name = 'Theme Vote Gender')
GROUP BY ue.player_key_id
HAVING theme_age > 1 
   AND theme_age < 100 
   AND theme_gender != 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for going into more detail. The MySQL version of the DB we're running is less than 8 and I don't have the ability to change the config. I went and tried your . If I run the query without any `GROUP BY` or `MAX` statements, I get output like in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jschuur/0e3a4e4c3a1ca7f998fcda368d20723c. So I get back multiple theme votes and the `GROUP BY` is intended to collapse each set of two rows from one player_key_id into a single row. But weirdly enough, I have more than two rows for some player keys, despite there only being two in the source data.

Comment: Please note this solution does not advise removing *any* `GROUP BY` but correcting it. Please explain why this solution does not work. `GROUP BY` should not be used to simply collapse rows to a single row but in context of aggregation.

Comment: I removed the `GROUP BY` statements to verify that the previous step still contains the data I'm looking for, albeit not quite in the format I want. Pre grouping, theme_vote values that range from 1-6 still exist. After grouping, only the max theme_vote value (6) across all rows remains, even though I grouped by the player_key_id and there are plenty of sets of player key based groups that contain a theme vote ID that wouldn't max to 6. I've added noted to the main post under 'For further clarification' to visualize why I'm using `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: This must be a data issue of which I cannot see anything. I tried your fiddle to no avail. Otherwise you either did not fully run my solution but partly kept your own or you did not fully check your own data (remember 6 is the default `ELSE` value of `CASE` or *any* string value that does not fit other categories). I seriously doubt MySQL is incorrectly calculating `MAX` with `GROUP BY` (specified correctly not your original). This would be an egregious bug recognized long before you did!